# map a nested list to another nested list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a nested list of People : List<List<People.>>, where People has two attribute int age, String name.
I want to map it to a nested list of Student, Student also has two attribute int age, String name.
So the output is List<List<Student.>>.I have looked at examples of mapping a List to another, something like this:

```
fun List<People>.convert(): List<Student>{
   return this.map {
    Student(
      age = this.age,
      name = this.name
    )
   }
}
```

How to do it with a nested list? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is one of Kotlin's [collection transformation operations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html). That link explains how it works.

Let's fix your `List<People>.convert()` function first. Here's one way to write it:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
data class Student(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun List<Person>.convert(): List<Student> {
    return this.map { person ->
        Student(
            age = person.age,
            name = person.name,
        )
    }
}
```

Note that inside the mapping function, `this` does not refer to anything, which is why your original code doesn't compile.

Since the mapping function we're passing to `map` has only one parameter, we can skip declaring the parameter, and refer to the argument by the special name `it` instead, like this:

```
fun List<Person>.convert(): List<Student> {
    return this.map { // it is Person
        Student(
            age = it.age,
            name = it.name,
        )
    }
}
```

Then, to convert a `List<List<Person>>` to a `List<List<Student>>` we could write:

```
val listsOfPeople: List<List<Person>> = listOf(
    listOf(Person("Alice", 27)),
    listOf(Person("Bob", 23), Person("Clarissa", 44))
)

val listsOfStudents: List<List<Student>> = listsOfPeople.map { // it is List<Person>
    it.convert()
}
```

Or, if you decide you don't need the `convert` function, you could write it like this:

```
val listsOfStudents: List<List<Student>> =
    listsOfPeople.map { // it is List<Person>
        it.map { // it is Person
            Student(it.name, it.age)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Exactly what I was looking for - I wasn't quite clear on the reference of "it" previously.